# How to solve this particular PDE using Feynman-Kac formula?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, pde, feynman-kac

I have to solve the PDE

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial y^2} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x \partial y} + y &= 0 \\
F(T,x,y) &= e^{x+y} 
\end{align}
$$

but I don't know how to do. Usually, when I have PDEs with cross derivatives, I use a translation $F(t,x,y) = G(t,z)$ (in this case it would be $e^{x+y} = e^z$). But now I have the term "$+y$" that makes this method useless since I get a term "$z-x$", so my PDE is a function both of $z$ and $x$. Do you know how to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Feynman Kac formula applies to parabolic PDEs. Your PDE, however, is elliptic because $\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}<0$.

Comment: So how can I solve that PDE?

Comment: Try some of the standard approaches: reduction to canonical form, separation of variables, Fourier/Laplace transform, Green's function, similarity reduction, generalised functions, ...  But that's no question about quantitative _finance_, it's purely a question about analysis. If you have more boundary conditions, you can set up a finite difference scheme and approximate the solution